# レビューの却下理由のリンクが間違っている

Tags: バグ, 完了

説明文中のURLが間違っています。というかtypoです。

> コピーされたコンテンツ
>   この編集の大半は第三者の著作物からコピーされたものです。百科事典や広告のような一般的な説明を使う代わりに、[このコミュニティで役立つ内容](hhttps://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)を考えてみてください。もし引用する際は必ず出典を明記してください。（参考: 他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typoを訂正しました。次回のビルドで適用されます。